# Inserting a loop into a Javascript number guessing game

Tags: javascript, loops

For an assignment, I need to make a JS number guessing game. It needs to include a loop to check the user's guess and a reset game button. My problem is getting the loop to work. I want the number of turns to start at 10. Each time the user makes an incorrect guess, their number of turns decreases by 1, and if they guess correctly, their number of turns is 0. If they push the "Start New Game" button, a new number should be generated and the number of turns should be reset to 10.

The loop doesn't specifically need to be a while loop, I just need one in the code for my assignment. Can anybody help me out?

```
<body>
    <!-- GAME INSTRUCTIONS -->
    <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated. Can you guess it?</p>
    <!-- FORM (Includes button to confirm guess, input box, and output box) -->
    <form id="Input" name="Input">
        <input name="guess" placeholder="Insert your guess" type="number">
        <input name="requestInfo" onclick="getResults()" type="button" value="Confirm">
        <p></p>
        <textarea cols="50" name="results" readonly="true" rows="8"></textarea>
        <p></p><input name="newGame" onclick="resetGame()" type="button" value="Start New Game">
    </form><!-- JAVASCRIPT START -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Define variables
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var turns = 10;

function checkNumber() {
    var guess = parseFloat(document.Input.guess.value);
    while (turns > 0) {
            if (guess == num) {
                turns = 0;
                document.Input.results.value = "Congratulations, you won! The mystery number was " + num + ".";
            } else if (guess < num) {
                turns--;
                document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too low. Turns remaining: " + turns;
            } else if (guess > num) {
                turns--;
                document.Input.results.value = "Your guess was too high. Turns remaining: " + turns;
            }
    }
}

function resetGame() {
    turns = 10;
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    document.Input.guess.value = "";
    document.Input.results.value = "";
}

function getResults() {
    checkNumber();
}
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I guess since it is a college/HS assignment your professor is trying to teach you using prompt under a loop.

```
<body>
<!-- GAME INSTRUCTIONS -->
<h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
<p>A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated. Can you guess it?</p>
<!-- FORM (Includes button to confirm guess, input box, and output box) -->
<form id="Input" name="Input">
    <input name="requestInfo" onclick="getResults()" type="button" value="Start Guessing!">
    <input name="newGame" onclick="resetGame()" type="button" value="Start New Game">
</form><!-- JAVASCRIPT START -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// Define variables
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var turns = 10;

function checkNumber() {
while (turns > 0) {
  guess=prompt("Tell me your guess.", "Your guess: ");
        if (guess == num) {
            turns = 0;
            alert("Congratulations, you won! The mystery number was " + num + ".");
        } else if (guess < num) {
            turns--;
            alert("Your guess was too low. Turns remaining: " + turns);
        } else if (guess > num) {
            turns--;
             alert("Your guess was too high. Turns remaining: " + turns);
        }
}
if (turns==0)
alert ("You failed to guess sadly.");
}

function resetGame() {
turns = 10;
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

function getResults() {
checkNumber();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would remove the loop, if I could. I did the exact same thing before learning that the teacher was requiring a loop for the assignment.

Comment: If you need loop you gotta shift the logic a bit. Want me to write it up for ya?

Comment: If you could, that'd be great

Comment: Done, take a look at it. It works good for me but it requires some optimization! Guess who's job is that? Yours! 
Good luck, been pleasure to assist you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the taks seems a bit weird - obviously, with a non-modal dialog, you will not need a loop.

One thing you could do is use the `prompt` method (example: `window.prompt("sometext","defaultText");`), which would then open a modal dialog to ask the user until the number of remaining guesses is zero, or until the guess was correct. That would work within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here have a go with this one. Makes sure that the user enters a number.

```
<body>
    <!-- GAME INSTRUCTIONS -->
    <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated. Can you guess it? Click button to start game.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="startNewGame()">Start New Game</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Define variables
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var turns;

function checkNumber() {
    while (turns > 0) {
        var guess = prompt("Insert your guess");
        if (!guess || isNaN(guess)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid number");
            continue;
        }
        if (guess == num) {
            alert("Congratulations, you won! The mystery number was " + num + ".");
            return;
        } else {
            turns--;
            if (guess < num) {
                alert("Your guess was too low. Turns remaining: " + turns);
            } else if (guess > num) {
                alert("Your guess was too high. Turns remaining: " + turns);
            }
        }
    }
    if (turns == 0) {
        alert("You have lost");
    }
}

function startNewGame() {
    turns = 10;
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    checkNumber();
}
</script>
</body>
```